# EJB3.1 - Transactions over multiple applications in the same JVM

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, jboss7.x

I've got the following situation:

- App1 ear — application that holds some services that do DB work.
- App2 ear — another application that uses App1 services.
- Both are running in the same JVM. The app server is JBoss7.
- App2 does some more DB work before/after calling App1's services.

Let's say in App2 in a service there is a method:

```
void method(){
   doDBWorkinApp2();
   callApp1ServiceToDoMoreDBWork();
   moreDBWorkinApp2();
}
```

I want this method to be executed in a single transaction. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using stateless or statefull beans?, can you show us how are declared the two beans?

Comment: The beans will be stateless. I'm interested if the persistence context will be propagated between the 2 applications. If an error occurs in moreDBWorkinApp2, then whatever work was done in callApp1ServiceToDoMoreDBWork(here a method from an injected bean from app1 will be called) is rolled back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming stateless, the transaction/persistence scope is in **general** propagated. But, take into the account the transaction attribute that you use for each method (i.e NOT_SUPPORTED, SUPPORTS, MANDATORY..) and some rules of propagation(the rules: [https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2006/10/persistence_con.html](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/ss141213/2006/10/27/persistence-context-propagation)).

*If a transaction-scoped entity manager is invoked from within a transaction, a new persistence context is created if there isn't one already and associated with the transaction* (Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0)

So, if you are using the default Tx attribute (REQUIRED) for the two stateless: They will share the same context, so, if 1 method fails **all** gets roll backed. If you dont want this behaviour you can still use something like (REQUIRES_NEW , NOT_SUPPORTED..)

To know more about transaction attributes: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html

EDIT: In the case of multiple EARs each EJB has a context (kind of client context) and will be propagated according to the TransactionAttribute of the EJB invoked, this is true only for local calls. Note that, you can't share the persistence context across remote EJB calls.

Comment: I'm familiar with transaction attributes and all the rules that must be respected within an application. My question is directed towards multiple application (different ears deployed in the same server). Can I work with different apps (each in its own ears) deployed on the same server in the same manner that I work with a single ear?

Comment: Considering that JBoss7 doesn't support local beans from other apps: https://community.jboss.org/thread/220857?start=0&tstart=0, the answer to my question is NO. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've finally had the time to test this and it is possible. When you have different persistence contexts XA transactions will be automatically created for you. Here's a link to a comment where I described the setup : https://community.jboss.org/thread/234302